Remix load route within route, like a reusable component
I am quite new to Remix and probably do not have the whole concept grasped correctly.
What I am trying to achieve is the following:
I want an endpoint which be displayed on /apicheck, this needs to know the user is authenticated in order to access.
In addition, I have a /dashboard which should show somewhere the apicheck content as well.
I come from a dotnet mvc background so the closest to this would be ViewComponents.
my structure is like this:
routes
 - dashboard.tsx
 - apicheck.tsx


apicheck.tsx would look like this
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {  
    console.log('apicheck loader called');
    
    var user = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
      failureRedirect: "/account/login",
    });
    let message = 1;
    return json({ message })
  };

export default function Apicheck() {
    console.log("Apicheck component rendered");
    const { message } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

    return (
      <div>
        { message }
      </div>
    );
  }

now then the dashboard.tsx
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {  
    console.log('Dashboard loader called');
    
    var user = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
      failureRedirect: "/account/login",
    });
    return user;
  };

export default function Dashboard() {
    console.log("Dashboard component rendered");

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>

        <Apicheck /> // here I call the other route.

      </div>
    );
  }

The issue is that when I call Apicheck as a component it never calls the loader, which makes sense as I am calling just the rendered part.
The question would be in the end, how can I inject the Apicheck route inside the Dashboard route and display it?
Edit:
Let me explain a bit my rationale. I want essentially to independent components that I can use anywhere. For example, let's say we have a language picker that needs to read something from the backend in order to display which language to show in the dropdown.
This element would be placed on the Navigation which sits inside the layout.
Currently, I am not able to make such a component with Remix standards and if I tried using just react, I won't have access to the authenticator. Hope this helps!

welcome to Remix! Routing takes some getting used to. You have a couple of options, the one I'd go for is extracting Apicheck as a component that takes props, let's say message, and the functionality that retrieves that message in the loader. Then reuse it in apicheck.tsx:
export default function ApicheckRoute() {
  console.log("Apicheck route rendered");
  const { message } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return <Apicheck message={message} />;
}

and in dashboard.tsx you retrieve the message in the loader and pass the message to Apicheck as well.
Another way to solve this problem is use a pathless layout route that envelopes both of your routes:
routes
 - _auth.tsx
 - _auth.dashboard.tsx
 - _auth.apicheck.tsx

This way you can inject a common loader to both of your routes. _auth.tsx is the layout route, it contains your loader and passes through your child routes with Outlet:
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {  
  console.log('auth layout loader called');
    
  var user = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {
    failureRedirect: "/account/login",
  });
  let message = 1;
  return json({ message })
};

export default function AuthLayout() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

Now your _auth.apicheck.tsx will look different, it should always use the output of the loader from _auth.tsx by using useRouteLoaderData():
export default function Apicheck() {
  console.log("Apicheck component rendered");
  const { message } = useRouteLoaderData<typeof authLoader>('_auth');

  return (
    <div>
      { message }
    </div>
  );
}

It should achieve the reusability that you're looking for, as long as you're rendering Apicheck from within an _auth.* route.
It's not ideal, though, because the authenticator.isAuthenticated() will be called twice  And it's a bit unconventional to share default route exports like that, that's why I would go for the first option, but you can make that call better.

hey @silvenon! thanks a lot for the reply. In both cases we have to kind of "prepare" the data from the callee and pass them down to the component. This hardly helps making decoupled pages or components, they are always dependant on the parent to load or provide the data.
Moreover this wont work when the language picker example is rendered in the layout and not in the main content.
Is there no other way? otherwise tbh Remix has really missed something here creating an insane tightly coupling.

currently, I went with another approach which is to use Resource routes that are called using fetcher and a useEffect. This essentially gives me the data I need and can protect the route while also using the data in the FE.
I will post it also as an answer when I flesh it out a bit more

The fetcher would’ve been my third suggestion, but it’s not server-rendered.

And yeah, it's tricky to make it entirely decoupled, each page rendering this component has to fetch data for it one way or another, and the component can't be decoupled form the data that it needs. Btw, based on your description and example code I assume that the auth API call in /apicheck is intended to halt the execution if the user is not authenticated, right? And which language picker are you talking about? There may be a way that suits your needs better, but I'm not entirely sure what those needs are, could you paint a more detailed picture?

Oh, I see that you edited your question. It sounds like this language picker is another example of a component that you're not sure how to build in Remix, but if it sits in your layout component, why can't it use data from that layout route's loader? And is the langauge picker somehow related to the Apicheck component?
